# RhinoMock - mocking multiple stubs for the same class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Say I have a class that is being called from within my `MainClass` method that I am testing.

```
public class MainClass
{
    private readonly SubClass;
    // constructor not shown
    public method TestMethod()
    {
        var data = SubClass.MethodA();

        // ...some code

        var moreData = SubClass.MethodB(someOtherData);

        // ...more code
    }
}
```

Using RhinoMock, I'd like to create a stub for `SubClass.MethodA()` to return a specified set of data in the test, however when calling `SubClass.MethodB()`, I want to call the original implementation.

I wouldn't want to break out the `SubClass'` two methods out into their own classes as they fit in `SubClass`. Is there a way in RhinoMock to stub out one method while calling another method in the same class (that is not a stub)?

Comment: Rhino mocks is ancient and harder to use. Have you looked at a more modern mocking library such as Moq or NSubstitute?

Comment: @CRice unfortunately that's not something I'm able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the extract and override test pattern and a simple stub for this.
This doesn't explicitly use Rhino though but will do for your scenario.

If you don't want to go down this path consider injecting Subclass into MainClass via a constuctor, public setter or parameter, and then you can have more control of mocking subclass first.

The idea is to make a virtual method that a sub class stub can override to take control of the behaviour of a part of a class under test.

```
public class MainClass
{
    private readonly SubClass _subClass;

    // constructor not shown
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var data = SubClassMethodACall();

        // ...some code

        var someOtherData = "";
        var moreData = _subClass.MethodB(someOtherData);

        // ...more code
    }

    protected virtual string SubClassMethodACall()
    {
        return _subClass.MethodA();
    }
}

public class SubClass
{

    public string MethodA()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string MethodB(string s)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

namespace Tests.Unit
{
    public class MainClassStub : MainClass
    {
        private readonly string _returnValueForMethodA;

        public MainClassStub(string returnValueForMethodA)
        {
            _returnValueForMethodA = returnValueForMethodA;
        }

        protected override string SubClassMethodACall()
        {
            return _returnValueForMethodA;
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            var mainClass = new MainClassStub("this is the test value returned");
            //.. rest of test
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This pattern is great for my scenario.